# Why are tires inflated?

Tags: automotive-engineering

My question is why are tires inflated? Wouldn't it just be better to make a rim out of a light but strong material, like fiber glass, then cover it with a thick coat of rubber, then it wouldn't pop if you run over a nail. I think my idea would be a lot better and would help a lot of people who otherwise would have got stranded in the middle of a desert.

Comment: Have you done any research on solid tyres, suspension etc before posting? Your « idea » is centuries old see for example cartwheels...

Comment: What about « run flat » tyres?

Comment: But why did they change from cartwheels to tires?

Comment: Have you ever tried riding a bike with a flat tyre? The air provides a serious amount of cushioning!

Comment: But now it can be popped and is much harder to ride on a flat.

Comment: "It's much harder to ride on a flat" is precisely why inflated tyres are preferred! You can get solid bicycle tyres, but imagine how heavy a solid car tyre would be compared to hollow... Now consider the extra energy required to get that spinning?

Comment: This is my point, I was saying you should use something light yet strong, like carbon fiber.

Comment: @DanielTurczynskyj There is that "thick coat of rubber" part.

Comment: Shocks take more of an impact whereas tires take durability. If tires were solid, you would feel every tiny little rock and bump as the shocks are intended for bigger impacts (different frequencies)

Comment: That's why I would add rubber, it would be a softer rubber that could take a beating.

Comment: Go invent this soft rubber that will take a beating and you will have something.   Don't forget it must be light.

Answer (score 1):

By filling the tire with air, we obtain a means by which shocks and bumps in the road surface can be prevented from reducing ride quality in the vehicle that rolls upon those tires.

In addition, an air-filled tire smooths out shocks which would otherwise be transmitted into and then damage the suspension mechanisms and the frame of the vehicle.

Air-filled tires also reduce the amount of damage to the roadway surface which would otherwise be inflicted by solid tires, especially at high speeds.

These days, tire technology is so good that it is rare to pop or burst a tire during normal operation unless the tire is underinflated. The occasional burst tire is a relatively small price to pay for the practical benefits of air-filled tires.